# Picking a str out of a sorted JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, sorting, lambda

I have this code:

```
import json
import random

y = {}
y['red'] = {'name': "red", 'p': 0, 'rand': 0}
y['blue'] = {'name': "blue", 'p': 0, 'rand': 0}
y['green'] = {'name': "green", 'p': 0, 'rand': 0}

with open('y.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(y, f)

f = open('y.json')
y = json.load(f)


for key, value in y.items():
    y[key]['rand'] = random.randint(1, 101)

sorted_keys = sorted(y.keys(), key=lambda x: y[x]['rand'])

for i, key in enumerate(sorted_keys):
    y[key]['p'] += i + 1


z = '%s%s%s' % (y['red']['name'], " ", y['red']['p'])
zz = '%s%s%s' % (y['blue']['name'], " ", y['blue']['p'])
zzz = '%s%s%s' % (y['green']['name'], " ", y['green']['p'])

a = sorted([z, zz, zzz], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)[0].split()[0]
b = "second"
c = "third"

print('\n'.join(sorted([z, zz, zzz], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)))
print( "\nWinner is:")
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

That calculates a random number for red, blue and green and sorts it in a table.

Now I want to say e.g. if red has the highest number, blue the 2nd and green the 3rd:

```
Winner is:
red
Second is:
blue
Third is:
green
```

I already have `Winner is: red` in my code, but don't know how to modify `sorted([z, zz, zzz], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)[0].split()[0]` to make it work for the second and third.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
a = sorted([z, zz, zzz], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)[0].split()[0]
b = sorted([z, zz, zzz], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)[1].split()[0]
c = sorted([z, zz, zzz], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)[2].split()[0]
```